# How to make git always warn to stash or commit changes before checking out a different branch?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-checkout

When I have modified my current branch and check out to a different branch, `git` warns me that I have not stashed or commited fails **only when there is a conflict between the two branches.**

How can I make git always warn me that files have not been commited before I checkout?

Comment: I think you just have to write a script that does this, and run that instead of `git checkout`. You can create a git alias for it, but I'm not aware of any config or client-side hook that would do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Useless says in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72346246/how-to-make-git-always-warn-to-stash-or-commit-changes-before-checking-out-a-dif#comment127809311_72346246), you will need to write your own little mini-program (e.g., a few lines of shell script or alias) that does this.  Git's "allow switching with modified files" is considered a *feature*, not a bug, and it specifically enables the creation of a new branch name at any time in case you have started work and decide that this should become a branch of its own.

The `git-core` library includes a `source`-able shell file named `git-sh-setup` that provides a function named `require_clean_work_tree`, so your alternate program (which you will use *instead of* `git checkout` or `git switch`) will likely begin with:

```sh
#! /bin/sh
. git-sh-setup

# adjust my-checkout name as desired
require_clean_work_tree my-checkout "stash or commit your changes before using my-checkout"
```

Note, however, that a *successful* `git checkout` or `git switch` that *carries modifications in the index and/or working tree* produces `git status` style output showing the carried modifications.  You can simply `git checkout -` or `git switch -` to return to the original branch name (or detached HEAD) that you were on just a moment ago.  There are a few rare corner cases where you'll lose some information in the process, but you are unlikely to run into these in practice.  For the gory details, see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).